# If statement does not complete code and skips getting user input

Tags: c++, if-statement, fstream, cin, cout

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <crime>
#include <stream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

char game;
char username;
char passwordOnline;
int password = 2427;
int password2 = 2724;
int answer1;
int answers;



int main()
{
cout << "Hello Welcome to PasswordHolder by ItsScrandy \n";
cout << "Please Enter The First Password: \n";
cin >> answer1;
cout << "Please Enter The Second Password \n";
cin >> answer2;

if (answer1 == password && answer2 == password2)
{
    cout << "What Is The Game Called? \n";
    cin >> game;

    cout << "What Is The Username/Email? \n";
    cin >> username;

    cout << "What Is The Password? \n";
    cin >> passwordOnline;
  }
    if (answer1 == password || answer2 == password2)
    {
        cout << "One of the password's you have enterd is incorrect";

    }
    else {
        cout << "Wrong Password";
    }

    //creating a .txt file 
    ofstream pctalk;
    pctalk.open("Login Details.txt", ios::app);

    //actually logging
    pctalk << "Game: " << game << " | " << "Username/Email: " << username << " | " << "Password: " << 
passwordOnline << "\n";
    //closing our file
    pctalk.close();
    return 0;
}
```

When I run code my program seems to work fine until it asks user for the game. after getting input 
it automatically runs the rest of the if statement. What is happening however is the secondary input if statements are bing skipped over and the rest of the code runs. Can anyone tell why these if statements are not being implemented properly?

Comment: `char` is a single character, you probably want `std::string` instead.

Comment: Okay, I've changed my chars to now strings. How would I use chars in this example? might be a dumb question but I'm interested in the answer for learning purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're evaluating the same in first and second statement for the passwords. In the firts statement:

```
if (answer1 == password && answer2 == password2)
```

In the second:

```
if (answer1 == password || answer2 == password2)
```

It's the same. Try this one for the second if statement:

```
if (answer1 != password || answer2 != password2)
```

Answer (score 0):

as other said
you use `char` instead of `std::string`

you have 3 `cin` in your code

```
cout << "What Is The Game Called? \n";
cin >> game;

cout << "What Is The Username/Email? \n";
cin >> username;

cout << "What Is The Password? \n";
cin >> passwordOnline;
```

if your game name have more than 3 character each cin gave 1 `char` because you just read 1 char and other chars remain in cin buffer

if you change this lines

```
char game;
char username;
char passwordOnline;
```

to

```
std::string game;
std::string username;
std::string passwordOnline;
```

it will work fine